# Connection refused when FTserver.c trying to connect to Ftclient.java

Tags: java, c, ftp, server, client

I am writing a file transfer client/server program where the server listens for a client, the client sends a -l (list of files in directory) or -g (get file) command. For some reason I keep getting a "error during connecting: Connection refused" error when setting up the data port connection. During the data connection the Java client is acting like a server and listening for the server to send over the directory list or the files. And the server is acting like a client in that it initiates the data connection. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Ftclient {

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private ServerSocket servSocket;
    private Socket dataSocket;
    PrintWriter out;
    BufferedReader in;
    BufferedReader stdIn;
    BufferedReader dataIn;
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

if (args.length < 4) {
        System.err.println(
            "Usage: java FtClient <host name> <port number> <command> <filename> <data_port>");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Ftclient one = new Ftclient();

    String hostName = args[0];
    int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    String command = args[2]; 
    int dataport = 0; boolean get = false;

one.initiateContact(hostName, portNumber);

    if (command.equals("-g")){
        get = true;
        String filename = args[3];
        dataport = Integer.parseInt(args[4]);
        command = command.concat(" ");
        command = command.concat(filename);
        command = command.concat(" ");
        command = command + dataport;
        System.out.println("command: " + command);
    }
    else if (command.equals("-l")){
        dataport = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        command = command.concat(" ");
        command = command + dataport;
        System.out.println("command: " + command);
    }
    one.out.println(command);

    String servResponse = one.in.readLine();
    if (servResponse != null){
        System.out.println(servResponse);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    one.dataListen(hostName, dataport);
    if (get){
        one.getFile();

    }
    else {
        one.getList();
    }

    one.dataSocket.close();
    one.clientSocket.close();


}

void initiateContact (String name, int portNumber) throws IOException{

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(name, portNumber);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in =
            new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " + name);}

}    

void dataListen (String name, int dataNumber)throws IOException{
    try {
        servSocket = new ServerSocket(dataNumber);

        dataSocket = servSocket.accept();

        System.out.println("data connection set up and listening");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get the dataport set up");
    }

}

void getList(){
    System.out.println("no lists for now");
}

void getFile(){
    System.out.println("no files for now");
}
```

}

ftserver.C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(1); } // Error function used for reporting issues
void startControl(int portNo);
void setupData(char* hostname, int dataport);

int listenSocketFD, establishedConnectionFD, portNumber, charsRead, charsWritten, socketFD;
socklen_t sizeOfClientInfo;
char buffer[256];
struct sockaddr_in serverAddress, clientAddress;
struct hostent *serverHostInfo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc < 2) { fprintf(stderr,"USAGE: %s port\n", argv[0]); exit(1); }

    // Set up the address struct for the server
    memset((char *)&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress));
    portNumber = atoi(argv[1]);

    startControl(portNumber);

    while (1){
        // Accept a connection, blocking if one is not available until one connects
        sizeOfClientInfo = sizeof(clientAddress); // Get the size of the address for the client that will connect
        establishedConnectionFD = accept(listenSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&clientAddress, &sizeOfClientInfo);
        if (establishedConnectionFD < 0) error("ERROR on accept");

        // Get the message from the client and display it
        memset(buffer, '\0', 256);

        printf("connection set up and ready to receive\n");
        charsRead = recv(establishedConnectionFD, buffer, 255, 0); // Read the client's message from the socket
        if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("SERVER: I received this from the client: \"%s\"\n", buffer);

        char *token; int dataport; char* filename; char* hostname;
        token = strtok(buffer, "#");
        if (strcmp(token, "-l") == 0){
            charsWritten = send(establishedConnectionFD, "list command", 13, 0);
            if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
            hostname = strtok(NULL, "#");
            printf("hostname %s\n", hostname);
            dataport = atoi(strtok(NULL, "#"));
            printf("datanum %d\n", dataport);
            setupData(hostname, dataport);
        }
        else if (strcmp(token, "-g") ==0){
            charsWritten = send(establishedConnectionFD, "file command", 13, 0);
            if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
            hostname = strtok(NULL, "#");
            printf("hostname %s\n", hostname);
            dataport = atoi(strtok(NULL, "#"));
            printf("datanum %d\n", dataport);
            filename = strtok(NULL, "#");
            printf("file %s\n", filename);
            setupData(hostname, dataport);
        }
        else {
            // send invalid
            charsWritten = send(establishedConnectionFD, "invalid command", 16, 0);
            if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");        
        }

        close(establishedConnectionFD); // Close the existing socket which is connected to the client

    }

    close(listenSocketFD); // Close the listening socket
    return 0; 
}

void startControl(int portNo){

    // Set up the socket
    listenSocketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create the socket
    if (listenSocketFD < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portNo);
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    // Enable the socket to begin listening
    if (bind(listenSocketFD, (struct sockaddr *)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) // Connect socket to port
        error("ERROR on binding");
    listen(listenSocketFD, 5); // Flip the socket on - it can now receive up to 5 connections
    printf("returning from startcontol right now\n");
}

void setupData(char* hostname, int dataport){
// Set up the server address struct
    memset((char*)&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress)); // Clear out the address struct
    portNumber = dataport; // Get the port number, convert to an integer from a string
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET; // Create a network-capable socket
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(portNumber); // Store the port number
    serverHostInfo = gethostbyname(hostname); // Convert the machine name into a special form of address
    if (serverHostInfo == NULL) { fprintf(stderr, "CLIENT: ERROR, no such host\n"); exit(0); }
    memcpy((char*)&serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr, (char*)serverHostInfo->h_addr, serverHostInfo->h_length);

    // Set up the socket
    socketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Create the socket
    if (socketFD < 0) error("CLIENT: ERROR opening socket");

    // Connect to server
    if (connect(socketFD, (struct sockaddr*)&serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) // Connect socket to address
        error("CLIENT: ERROR connecting");

    // Get input message from user
    printf("CLIENT: Enter text to send to the server, and then hit enter: ");
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer)); // Clear out the buffer array
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, stdin); // Get input from the user, trunc to buffer - 1 chars, leaving \0
    buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0'; // Remove the trailing \n that fgets adds

    // Send message to server
    charsWritten = send(socketFD, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0); // Write to the server
    if (charsWritten < 0) error("CLIENT: ERROR writing to socket");
    if (charsWritten < strlen(buffer)) printf("CLIENT: WARNING: Not all data written to socket!\n");

    // Get return message from server
    memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer)); // Clear out the buffer again for reuse
    charsRead = recv(socketFD, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0); // Read data from the socket, leaving \0 at end
    if (charsRead < 0) error("CLIENT: ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("CLIENT: I received this from the server: \"%s\"\n", buffer);

    close(socketFD); // Close the socket

}
```

Comment: I know the issue is in my setupData function in the ftserver.c because I can telnet and my Java client will accept the data connection

Comment: the posted C code does not compile.  Amongst other things, it is missing the needed `#include` statements.  Is that actually how the C code is written?

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.  2)  consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.

Comment: when calling the function: `listen()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding this code block: `if (p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Server data connect: failed to find address\n");
    exit(1);
}`.   the pointer `p` will always be NULL at this point in the code, due to the prior `for()` loop

Comment: the posted C code does nothing when it makes a '`connect()` to some server.  What is it expected to do at that time?

Comment: I have added the #include and import statements. Right now the error I get is that it enters the for loop in setupData() but keeps saying server data connection: error connecting Connection Refused. As for the listen(), you are right but I know it's successful because the control connection works and I can send data over it. As for the connect(), after the data connection is set up it is supposed to send over a list of all files in the directory. I know the Java client is listening() for this file because if I connect using telnet and the dataport # it works

Comment: did you read my comment about the code block that starts with: `if(p ==NULL)`?  That tells you exactly why nothing is getting done.

Comment: I've removed that

Comment: I resolved it by adding a do-while loop to try connecting a few times, int numConnections < 10

Comment: regarding this line: `memset((char *)&serverAddress, '\0', sizeof(serverAddress));`   The function: `memset()` is expecting the first parameter to be a `void*` so why cast it to `char*`?

Comment: regarding these two lines: `charsWritten = send(establishedConnectionFD, "file command", 13, 0);
            if (charsRead < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");`.  The call to `send()` assigns its' returned value to `charsWritten` BUT the error checking is looking at `charsRead`  Probably not what you want.